# Is there a way to make scrolling finer for a scrollable object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax

Let's say there's a scrollable `<div>` or `<body>` that has a height of 2000px. Everytime I use the mouse scroll, it will unfold *100 pixels*. Is there a way to make the unfolding **10px** instead of **100px**?
So that the scrolling would seem to be finer.

Comment: Probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564561/how-to-specify-how-many-pixels-scroll-moves-on-each-step

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar post answering what you want.
[Change Scroll Speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426548/how-to-change-default-scrollspeed-scrollamount-scrollinertia-of-a-webpage) with a fiddle for demo.

NOTE: I think this is a bad idea as far as use-ability and respect for the user. AND i dont think you can actually change the speed. You just 'fake it' by changing the amount of scroll over an element. If you had a wrapper around your page i suppose it would work.

If you want to get a parallax effect, there is some jquery plugins

[Stellar plugin](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/docs/)

[Scrolling Parallax Plugin](http://jonraasch.com/blog/scrolling-parallax-jquery-plugin)